# Quantifier evaluation using translation to english

Tags: quantifiers

Which one of the following well-formed formulae is a tautology?
$\hspace {2pt}$ a)$\forall x \exists y R(x,y) \leftrightarrow \exists y \forall x R(x,y) $
$\hspace{2pt}$b)$\forall x[\exists y\hspace{1pt} R(x,y)\rightarrow S(x,y)]\rightarrow \forall x \exists y \hspace{1pt} S(x,y)$
$\hspace{2pt}$c)$\forall x \exists y[P(x,y)\rightarrow R(x,y)]\leftrightarrow \forall x\exists y(\neg P(x,y) \lor R(x,y))$
$\hspace{2pt}$d)$\forall x \forall y P(x,y)\rightarrow \forall x \forall y P(y,x)$

Now, let x be set of all boys, y be set of all girls, R(x,y): x loves y P(x,y): x knows y S(x,y); x marries y, then
a) **Every boy loves some girl** is not equivalent to **Some girl is loved by every boy**
b)**For every boy, if he loves a girl then he marries that girl** doesnot imply **Every boy marries a girl** as in the left side, a boy might love some girl but get married to some one else.
c) RHS is the expansion of implication.
d) **Every boy knows every girl** doesn't imply **Every boy is known by Every girl**
Is this correct way to interpret?

Comment: I agree with your interpretations.

Comment: For option d, i am taking quantifier to have highest precedance, is that ryt?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by taking quantifier to have the highest precedance? Your interpretation:  Every boy knows every girl doesn't imply every boy is known by every girl is correct since x comes before y

Comment: @JesseMeng [Order of operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Notational_conventions)  Implication is evaluated after quantifiers unless bracetted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now, let x be set of all boys, y be set of all girls, R(x,y): x loves y, P(x,y): x knows y, S(x,y): x marries y, then

For a start, you don't declare *different* implicit domains for entities outside the statement; the literals are untyped.   Well, we'll let that slide this time.

> > a)$\hspace {2ex}\forall x ~\exists y~ R(x,y) ~\leftrightarrow~ \exists y ~\forall x~R(x,y) $
>
> a) **Every boy loves some girl** is not equivalent to **Some girl is loved by every boy**

$\color{red}\checkmark$ Okay

> > b)$\quad\forall x~[\exists y~ R(x,y)\rightarrow S(x,y)]\rightarrow \forall x ~\exists y ~ S(x,y)$

Order of operations places $S(x,y)$ outsode the scope of the first existential.  Assuming that is unintentional, the brace should occur after the quanitfication rather than before.

$$\quad\forall x~\exists y~ [R(x,y)\rightarrow S(x,y)]~~\rightarrow~~\forall x ~\exists y ~ S(x,y)$$

> b)**For every boy, if he loves a girl then he marries that girl** doesnot imply **Every boy marries a girl** as in the left side, a boy might love some girl but get married to some one else.

$\color{red}\chi$ No, that's not the reason it is not a tautology.   What you need to consider is that *not* every boy may love some girl.

> > c)$\quad\forall x~\exists y~[P(x,y)\to R(x,y)]~\leftrightarrow~ \forall x~\exists y~(\neg P(x,y) \lor R(x,y))$
>
> c) Both are negation of one another.

$\color{red}\chi$ No, they are not.   Try again.

> > d)$\qquad\forall x~\forall y~P(x,y)~~\rightarrow~~\forall x~\forall y~P(y,x)$
>
> d) **Every boy knows every girl** doesn't imply **Every boy is known by Every girl**
>
> Is this correct way to interpret?

$\color{red}\checkmark$ Indeed, that is okay.

Comment: I have edited translation of c, thanks for pointing out, it was unintentional